# ClassCastException ((MainActivity)getActivity()).clearApp();

Tags: android, classcastexception

If I call `((MainActivity)getActivity()).clearApp();` in my PrefsFragment. I get this error... why?

How can I fix this iusse and get understand this error.

```
08-22 12:33:10.833 13362-13362/com.my.blacky E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.blacky, PID: 13362
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.my.blacky.PrefsActivity cannot be cast to com.my.blacky.MainActivity
   at com.gerpue.blacky.FragmentPrefs$2.onPreferenceClick(FragmentPrefs.java:62)
   at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:996)
   at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:214)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1188)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3105)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4096)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: You are currently in  PrefsActivity  And trying to cast with MainActivity.

Comment: ((PrefsActivity)getActivity()).clearApp(); check like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the method clearApp();  is present in the MainActivity or PrefsActivity ?

If it is in PrefsActivity then you can try some thing like this

```
((PrefsActivity)getActivity()).clearApp();  // because You are currently in PrefsActivity
```

If the method is in MainActivity and still you want to use the method from PrefsFragment( PrefsFragment fragment inside the  PrefsActivity ). Declare the clearApp() method as static and access like below

```
MainActivity.clearApp();
```

clearApp method should be like this in MainActivty

```
public static void clearApp()
{
       // your implementation 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is in the MainActivity and this is the solution!

Comment: Welcome. Could you accept the answer so that it will be not fall into unanswered questions

Comment: But wenn I have to use a non static method?

Comment: I Use the  Sharedpref "setting" to save "istheFirstRun" and in the .clearApp() I call.... setting.edit().clear().apply(); But  wenn i Change to static

Comment: I get the Error: Non-static field 'setting' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: you can make it static field.